# Converting a Hex String (from WPF TextBox) into byte

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, hex, byte

I write small WPF application. In my app I have one field called `Seq` which is actually the byte data.

So `Seq` field should get updated via `TextBox` of the WPF application. But Text string will be typed in Hex format without leading 0x.

Basically I need to write down the algorithm to complete the set method of `Seq` to set only one byte of data.

Object class which gets updated via text box:

```
public class WProtocol {
     private byte _seq
     public byte Seq {
         get {
             return _seq;
         }
         set {
             _seq = value;
         }
     }
 }
```

`WFrameWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class WFrameWindow: Window {
    WProtocol m_WProtocol = new WProtocol();
    public WFrameWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = m_WProtocol;
    }
}
```

Snippet from `WFrameWindow.xaml` to show binding the of the source:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="115,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{***Binding Seq,Mode=OneWayToSource , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged***}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial"/>
```

Comment: Is only one byte or byte array?

Comment: As of now I have only one byte data not an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution would be;

```
    private string _seq_string;
    public string SeqString
    {
        get { return _seq_string; }
        set
        {
            _seq_string = value;
            SeqBytes = StringToByteArray(value); 

        }
    }

    public byte[] SeqBytes {  get; set; }


    public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string hex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                         .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                         .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                         .ToArray();
    }
```

and XAML code would be:

```
<TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="115,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{***Binding SeqString,Mode=OneWayToSource , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged***}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

My proposed answer is using a converter instead of code in the ViewModel:

The XamlCode:

```
 <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="24" Margin="115,26,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
          Text="{Binding Seq, Converter={StaticResource StringToByteConverter}, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="99" FontSize="9" FontFamily="Arial"/>
```

The Converter:

```
public class StringToByteConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is String)
        {
            string valueTyped = (String)value;

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(valueTyped) == false && valueTyped.Length <= 2)
                return System.Convert.ToByte(valueTyped, 16);
        }

        return new byte();

    }
}
```

To use the converter, add it in the Resources:

```
...
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
...

<Application.Resources>
    <local:StringToByteConverter x:Key="StringToByteConverter"/>
```

Comment: where to modify for the resources mentioned in the last bit of your answer?

Comment: in the Window / UserControl / App xaml file. It depends on where you intend on using it. If you define it in the App.xaml file, you can access it in the entire application.

Comment: I need to extend the ConvertBack method for  array as I have few more fields which can take either 0ne or  two bytes. So before I convert the Hex string to byte array , I should do the validity check (hex string length) received from text box. So any other way  of defining the Byte length while Binding the resource in the xaml file and do the validity check in ConvertBack  based on Byte length.